# Can IE 11 save the current DOM?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, dom

How can I save the current DOM using IE 11.
For IE 11, specifically, I can find no save buttons or keys, no documentation, no advice.

Comment: Save DOM where? The DOM is just an API, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do?  Are you trying to save (download) the page to your computer?  Are you trying to save the page into a JavaScript variable?

Comment: the computed source is obtained with
document.documentElement.outerHTML typed in the Console tab... it should closely match the DOM Explorer tab's text which you can also copy and paste to a text file.
hosted iframe dynamic content (eg. google analytics iframes) with
document.frames[n].document.documentElement.outerHTML or click on the iframe element in the DOM Explorer tab of dev tools to expand its tree.